# reinforcement learning: dealing with unquantifiable feedback system

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to write a reinforcement learning algorithm which for simplicity will predict a number that I'm thinking of by taking n inputs [shouldn't be important what they are]. So when the algorithm predicts a number, i'll just respond it saying 'very close' 'close' 'exact' 'far' 'too far'

Now all the tutorials I've seen have a quantifiable result and they usually do a mean square error to see how much of error was there in the prediction. But here the feedback is unquantifiable

How do I approach this problem? FYI i'm very new to ML
It's not necessary for it to be a reinforcement learning. I also tried for neural network approach but even that had similar issues

Answer (score 0):

If you approached this using simple linear regression, you would train a model based upon prior examples. The `n` inputs and what the actual answer was for each one of those inputs would be used to create a linear equation that most closely satisfies all of the example data. When asking for a prediction, the `n` inputs are fed through this equation and this result will be the prediction.

With reinforcement learning, an agent is trained based on "rewards" experienced in the environment from taking certain actions in a set of states. These rewards must be quantifiable. To use RL methods, you need to quantify your set of responses. I would imagine that 'exact' would have a large positive reward associated with it, 'close' to have a small positive reward, and 'far' to have a negative reward associated with it. You must quantify your feedback in some way otherwise the RL agent will not be able to "learn."

You can still use RMSE as a measure for your policy's accuracy by measuring the difference between the predicted number and what the result should be. You should have access to the actual result, otherwise how would know if the prediction is exact, close, or far?